# OAuth token revocation for Forgot password

Tags: oauth-2.0

Should the Oauth tokens be revoked if the customer goes through a forgot password flow and changes his password

Answer (score 5):

One reason for changing a password is when a user notices that someone else had access to his account. In this case an attacker who had once access with the old password and used OAuth to get an access token could still have access to the account, though the user changed his password to prevent this.

E.g. for some obscure reason (weak password, trojan, etc.) your GMail account was hacked and used to send spam. The attacker used [Google's IMAP with OAuth feature](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) and got a valid access token. Now somehow you notice they're sending spam in your name and you change your password. The attacker still has a valid access token and can continue sending spam.

Revoking the token should be independent of the reason, why the user changes his password. If he changes it, you should revoke all tokens and let him sign up once again.