# Revoking OAuth tokens in Mule

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule

I have configured a OAuth provider in Mule using the [OAuth connector](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Using+a+Connector+to+Access+an+OAuth+API), and I give out access tokens to users as and when they login, they get a new access token for each device they login with, my question is what is the best thing to do when a user enters in a forgot password or reset password scenario ?

In this case he wants to revoke access to all the devices which have been given access, so it basically implies revoking all the access token given out ... The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678905/oauth-token-revocation-for-forgot-password) seems to suggest that the above is a valid approach, so now my question boils down to the best implementation technique in mule.

Mule does allow the revocation of tokens via `<oauth2-provider:revoke-token />` but using it requires me to maintain a list of access token given out against each user, I am wondering if this is the only way to handle things in mule ?

Comment: Can you query the object-store to retrieve all the tokens associated with a resource owner? This is an EE module so I unfortunately can't check that for you...

Comment: The OAuth component uses the objectMemory store internally and if we assume that we could get all token associated with a RO, do you reckon that would be enough, would'nt we need to have a list of tokens given out for a particular username ?

Comment: I will touch base with Mule support and see if I can get any updates on this in the meanwhile.

Comment: That's the best. I hope you can avoid to maintain such extra user -> token association and re-use something internal...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80009/discussion-between-david-dossot-and-sudarshan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Mulesoft had to say for the query.

> Unfortunately, current code does not have(or expose) the methods to:
>
> - revoke all tokens granted to a user
> - get all tokens granted to a user

They have decided to log an enhancement for this and that will take its due course, will update the answer with a link once I have it. Here goes the issue [link](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8701)

The way I have implemented this in the pass is to use the objectstore to main a list of token issued against a given username, this list will need to be appended to with a new token each time a user logins.

If the user initiates a password reset or forgot password flow then pull all the token against the user and invoke `<oauth2-provider:revoke-token />` for each token.

Do let me know if you have any suggestions on the above.